# R : REST API, reading post parameters

Tags: r

Below is my REST-POST-API code

```
#* @post /run
process <- function(req, execute, input=""){
  #print(req)
  writeLines("post request\n")
  cat('input:- ',input)
  writeLines("\n")

  cat('body :- ',req$postBody)
  writeLines("\n")

  source(file = execute)
  readData_xl()
  #readData_xl(filepath)
}
```

below is JSON payload

```
{
    "execute": "processing_xl_data.R",
    "input": "[{'three':'3'},{'four':'4'}]",
    "filepath":"C://abc//mydata.xlsx"
}
```

below are the logs from console

post request

input:-  [{'three':'3'},{'four':'4'}]

body :-  `{     "execute": "processing_xl_data.R",     "input": "[{'three':'3'},{'four':'4'}]",         "filepath":"C://abc//mydata.xlsx" }`

**my question is how to read "filepath" from pyload.?**
*PS : i dont want to add one more extra parameter (filepath) to the function process.*

**i tried something like this** *req$postBody$filepath* **but it did not work**

Comment: From your question it is not really clear what `req$postBody` is. I guess it is a character? In that case before you can select elements of it, you should parse it using e.g. `jsonlite::fromJSON(req$postBody)`. Please provide us with samples of the objects you are dealing with (using e.g. `dput`), for it is very difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: req$postBody printed the entire json payload which i passed as part of POST api

Comment: any have thanks for the help. from jsonlite package i'm able to read the post parameters